# Is it correct in terms of principle, to use `import` statement to import file types other than JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack

Does using the JavaScript import statement for images, css and others  defeat the purpose of import statement which was designed to import only the JS Modules ?

Of course, for now it gets transpiled to ES5 `require` using webpack. But that same question comes up again. Is it incorrect to use import statement to import images or css or files ?

EDIT:

I like the idea of controlling imports that we can control the assets on build time in such a clean way - The idea that I use the image path to import the image, and

- on different environments the image path would contain different values - url or path
- this image can be compressed on build time
- the JS module importing this image can contain the image dimensions through a custom loader
- assets dependency tree is maintained at one place and un-imported items gets chucked away automatically
- rebuild time is fast - DX(developer experience) would be good

I guess, this is much better than using any templating, using placeholders in the JS files to inject URLs or paths based on environment during `pre-build (webpack)`.

But using the `import` statement feels not right to do so in terms of principle or semantics.

Answer (score 0):

This is from Mozilla Developer Network:

> The import statement is used to import functions that have been exported from an external module, another script, etc.

From everything I've read on MDN and other sources its purpose is to make a module/script methods and properties available within the current scope it's being imported into.